# Git remote add origin: correct URL and path to add remote repo on the local network

Tags: macos, git, ssh

I am trying to set up a remote repository on a Mac on my local network.  I have done the following:

- Set the sharing privileges on the remote, allowing access to all users (using System Preferences/Sharing)
- confirmed that I can SSH to the remote machine
- created the repo in the remote directory
- created a repo in the local machine directory
- executed this command from the local repo directory:

  `git remote add origin FSM13@192.168.1.51:/Library/FileMaker\ Server/HTTPServer/htdocs/fm-php`
- when I attempt to push:

  `git push -u remote origin master`
- I get these errors:

  `fatal: 'remote' does not appear to be a git repository`

  `fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`
- I get the same error using this syntax to set the remote

  `git remote add origin ssh://FSM13@192.168.1.51/Library/FileMaker\ Server/HTTPServer/htdocs/fm-php`

FMS13 is the administrator user account on the remote machine.

What steps might I be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were three things I needed to do in order to solve this issue:

- set up the SSH Keys correctly
- initialize the remote repo correctly (using --bare) (this worked but I need to try a few more things.  a bare repo does not have any files, just the history: http://www.saintsjd.com/2011/01/what-is-a-bare-git-repository/ )
- set the path correctly for the git remote add command

Note that I am using OS X.

This youtube vid and blog post laid it out perfectly:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DDzeiI2yZL8
- http://crosbymichael.com/setup-password-less-login-over-ssh.html

---

SSH Keys:
On the local machine, starting from home directory:

```
cd .ssh
cat id_rsa.pub
```

then copy the printed public key.  I happened to already have one.  The blog post above explains how to create one.

SSH into the remote:

```
ssh FMS13@192.168.1.51
ls -a
```

Is there a .ssh directory?  If not create one.  It needs to be in the home directory.

```
mkdir .ssh
cd .ssh
```

then create a keys file

```
touch authorized_keys
nano authorized_keys
```

Then paste the key and save the file.

Confirm the install of the key by ssh'ing from the local machine:

```
ssh FMS13@192.168.1.51
```

No password was requested, so the key install was successful

---

Correct repo initialization:
On the remote machine, cd to the desired parent directory and:

```
mkdir remote-git
cd remote-git
git init --bare
```

---

On the local machine from the repo directory, the correct path was as follows to set the remote origin:

```
git remote add origin ssh://FMS13@192.168.1.51/Users/FMS13/Desktop/remote-git
```

Where FMS13 is the user on the remote computer, followed by the ip address and then the full path to the  directory of the remote repo.

---

Push to remote:

Then back in the local machine, cd to the repo directory and:

```
git push origin --all
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used something similar to this command recently which worked for me:

`git remote set-url origin ssh://FSM13@192.168.1.51/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git`

Check out [this link](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url) for more information. For your case, you may need to be adding the following instead. I have not seen using an IP address with this, though- so refer to the link.

```
ssh://git@192.168.1.51/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
```

You may also need to generate a new ssh key. [Here is a link on that](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys):

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com"
```

Comment: This has not worked either.  I also tried: 'git remote set-url origin FMS13@192.168.1.51:Library/FileMaker\ Server/HTTPServer/htdocs/fm-php.git'

Comment: you put FSM13 where username is in the command? I think you're supposed to put the url, not the IP

Comment: I did not: I used the full path to the repo.  I will try what you suggest.

Comment: This did not work either: 'git remote set-url origin FMS13@192.168.1.51/FMS13/fm-php.git' and this did not work: 'git remote set-url origin FMS13@192.168.1.51:FMS13/fm-php.git'

Comment: What about git remote set-url origin ssh://git@192.168.1.51:FMS13/fm-php.git  ?

Comment: Well with that last one I am getting a password prompt when I 'Git push -u origin master' but the password, which I a certain is correct fails three times then errors out with this error:
Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: Do I need to set up a key on the remote computer? Local?